# is oscillating voltage of circuit in positive direction still considered as AC voltage?

Tags: ac, dc, rectifier

suppose an AC voltage is supplied with DC offset for which the crest and trough of the wave are all in positive y direction of the graph. for example v=10+sin(20t). is this still considered as AC voltage even though the voltage isn't negative at any moment?

I have been told that this voltage is still AC voltage. even fully rectified AC current without filter and capacitor is partly AC too. does that mean any sort of oscillation makes the current AC even though it is in positive direction?

Comment: That depends on who you ask so it attracts opinionated answers. For some people anything that is not pure DC will be AC, and therefore for them even DC batteries that are charged and discharged once a year is AC. For other people it takes a voltage polarity change to call it AC. For other people, it takes a change in current flow direction to be called AC. For some people a 3V logic square wave is AC and for some it's chopped DC and not AC. Sorry but you won't get a consistent answer asking this here without people arguing how they are taught with this matter.

Comment: Shouldn't sentences start with a lowercase letter in the English language?